Switched mode PS2 power supply failure
I have this power supply coming from a japanese PS2:

Since I’m stupid, I plugged it into 220V, but this thing is designed for 100V only… the 4A/125V fuse popped out after a couple of seconds.
Since I’m very very stupid, I replaced the fuse with a 4A/220V (it’s impossible to find 125V fuses in my country) and I bought a 220V->110V AC adapter (I tested it and its output was 110V AC as it should be).
I then tried again: I gave 110V to the PSU and the green light turned on for few seconds, then turned off. I also started getting some bad smell, so I disconnected everything. I discovered that the AC adapter has no output at all now, probably is burnt… I guess some overcurrent happened?
Looking at the pcb, I don’t see any evident issue. I measured the thermistor, 3R910, without desoldering it, (which should fail for overcurrent), it has 6.2 ohms at room temperature.
My questions are:

what caused the AC adapter to fail? I suppose an overcurrent, but I would like to have confirmed this idea
if an overcurrent happened, the 4A fuse should have popped, right? Even though the rated voltage is 220V instead of 110V?
which components do you suggest to start checking to understand the issue?


Is there a schematic and/or parts list available for the power supply? Failing that, it looks like a single sided PCB, and are you able to reverse-engineer a schematic? Having a schematic would help to identify components which could be damaged by an over-voltage (before the fuse popped).

@ChesterGillon I googled 1-468-726-21 but could not find anything. And yes, it seems a single sided PCB, I’m updating the post with a picture of the back

You should check every component inside the hatched silkscreen outline, because essentially all of them are now suspect. Some of the ones outside it may be damaged too, but the ones on the primary side would be damaged quicker. If the PSU was attached to any sort of load (i.e. connected to the rest of the PS2), there's a chance the load (PS2) is damaged as well, but there's a good chance it's fine, too.


You destroyed it with overvoltage by plugging a 100VAC device into 220VAC mains. The main bulk capacitor is rated for 220VDC which is good for rectified 100VAC being about 140VDC, but rectified 220VAC is about 320VDC. At least the capacitor should be damaged, maybe other parts too. The type of your 220VAC to 110VAC converter is important, most of them are "electronic" and intended for powering simple motors like razors and cannot be used on things like mains power supplies.

The fuse voltage is a rating it can safely withstand and work normally. You can use a 250VAC fuse in place of 125VAC fuse safely, but you cannot safely use a 125VAC fuse on 220VAC device - which you already did. The fuse is not rated to safely cut 220VAC as it may keep conducting as a plasma arc after the wire has blown. In any case, the fuse voltage is likely not an issue. You can use 1000V fuse as long as it's other ratings match, 4A and fast/slow blow. Which you seem not to consider at all.

All of them. Overvoltage may have damaged many components. Sometimes there is only one power supply design but small differences to make 100VAC supplies cheaper. Sometimes the difference is literally the capacitor being rated for lower voltage, but there may be other differences.


